# Combining android navigation drawer with the search box of Android Persistent Search Library

Tags: java, android, search-box, navigation-drawer

I am developing an app in which I am using search bar from [Android Persistent Search Library](https://github.com/Quinny898/PersistentSearch) on github. In my app I have a default navigation drawer activity provided by android studio. The search bar looks like this:
[image: persistent search box]

I want to open my navigation drawer on clicking the hamburger icon in the search box. Is there any way of combining these two? Currently when I click the hamburger icon a method `onMenuClick()`
is called and a toast is displayed saying "Menu Click".
How can I change this `onClick` to open up my navigation drawer?
Any help is appreciated.

Here is the code of my activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SearchBox search = (SearchBox) findViewById(R.id.searchbox);
        search.enableVoiceRecognition(this);

        search.setLogoText("Enter your search term here...");
        search.setMenuListener(new SearchBox.MenuListener(){

            @Override
            public void onMenuClick() {
                //Hamburger has been clicked
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Menu click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well you didn't show any code so that i can't tell you want to change, but this is how you can open a drawer which is at the left hand side

```
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id."provide your draer id here");
  drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
```

you have to write this code inside `onMenuClick()` that you may open the drawer

and if the navigation drawer have  `android:layout_gravity="right"`, use this

```
drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
```